# Does anyone know the rank of the Netflix Prize dataset?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, recommender-system, sparse

I'm looking into the [Netflix Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize) at the moment. We model the dataset as an $n \times m$ matrix, where $n$ is the number of users and $m$ is the number of movies. Does anyone know the rank of the original dataset provided by Netflix?

- If so: what is the rank? If a computationally tractable approach exists, what is it?
- If not: why not? Is it computationally intractable?

By rank of a matrix $M$, I mean the dimension of the vector space spanned by the columns of $M$. This is well defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

The Netflix Prize matrix $M$ has 100,480,507 entries, 480,189 rows, and 17,770 columns. 1.17% of the entries are nonzero.

Comment: Could you explain to us what the "rank" of a dataset might be?

Comment: I think in most cases, the Netflix Prize dataset is modeled as a matrix. So, by "rank" I mean the rank of the matrix. I clarified this above as well. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @whuber I'm new to this process -- is there anything else I can do to remove the [on hold] status?

Comment: @stats_man97531 it's not really a question about statistics - I think you are better off asking in reddit\machinelearning or datascience and possibly in datascience stackexchange.  also not sure that matrix factorisation was the standard method used  - it was one component of the winning algorithm

Comment: @whuber, one methodology to build recommender systems is so called matrix factorisation, where one attempts to reconstruct/impute the sparsely populated user x item matrix by assuming it is the product of two low rank matrices.

Comment: @sean Thank you.  The issue with the original question was that "rank" can mean so many different--and possibly applicable--things in this context that I felt it was important to ask for explicit clarification.  After all, don't Netflix consumers "rank" shows and weren't the entries in the competition "ranked"?

Comment: So I *think* the rank is not defined ( because the whole point is that you are trying to reconstruct a matrix with mostly missing/unknown values)

Comment: In these schemes, the missing values are 0 entries, so the rank is defined. My question is getting at this point: nobody has bothered to find the rank and share it so far. Why not?

Comment: also, as you mentioned, the winning paper used SVD as a part of the solution. They SVD'd the matrix with missing entries as 0 (they just didn't compute all the singular values greater than or equal to 0 so the rank is still unknown).

Comment: There's a really interesting computational linear algebra question buried in here. The rank of the Netflix dataset is a bit of trivia, but an algorithm to compute the rank of a massive, sparse matrix would be extremely helpful to know! For example, using [tag:svd] is probably prohibitively expensive because the singular vectors must be stored as dense matrices for iterative updates, so the memory requirements would be enormous.

Comment: Could you state the dimension (number of rows and columns) and how sparse (percent nonzero entries) the Netflix data is? That would help inform answers about how, algorithmically, one should go about determining the rank.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's getting more on the nose. Is it computationally tractable to find the rank of a large, sparse matrix? The memory requirements for SVD are huge. I've added the info you requested in the original question - thanks for the help/interest :)

Comment: I would start with Chapter 10 of *Matrix Computations* (4th Ed) by Golub & van Loan. I'm not a specialist in numerical linear algebra, so I do not know if there are better or more recent methods.

Comment: Will do -- thank you @Sycorax. Out of curiosity, you say that "an algorithm to compute the rank of a massive, sparse matrix would be extremely helpful to know!". Do you have specific examples/motivations? Why would the rank (in and of itself) be useful?

Comment: Suppose you do the naive thing and have a giant computer calculate the SVD. After spending a lot of money and waiting a long time, you find out that the rank is merely $k\approx\frac{1}{1000}\min\{m,n\}$. This procedure is more than a little wasteful, because you also computed left- and right-singular vectors for way more singular values than necessary. If instead you could know the rank **cheaply**, you could be much more efficient in all of your downstream tasks because you know ahead of time that you only need to care about $k$ components, so you know how to "right-size" autoencoders etc.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for taking the time. I've snagged a copy of Matrix Computations and will see what I can do!